# Pressure integrated by parts in finite element method

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, finite-element-method

Most FEM texts or tutorials apply FEMs on diffusion equations where the 2nd spatial derivative is integrated by parts during weak formulation. For convection diffusion equations, there is a first spatial derivative term not integrated by parts. But in Navier-Stokes, $\nabla p$, a first spatial derivative, is integrated by parts, why?

Answer (score 4):

The two weak formulations of the Stokes equation,
$$\int_\Omega\bigl(\nabla\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\psi_i+\psi_i\nabla p \bigr) dV=0,$$
and
$$\int_\Omega\bigl(\nabla\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\psi_i-p \nabla\psi_i\bigr) dV=0,$$
with $\psi_i$ a test function which vanishes on the boundary of $\Omega$, are both in use. (For the first formulation without partial integration of the pressure term, see [Burkardt's lecture notes,](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/classes/fem_2011/fem_ns3.pdf) section 4.)

The first formulation requires that both the velocity field and the pressure field must be $C^1(\Omega)$, in the second formulation the pressure can be $C^0(\Omega)$. It depends on application-specific reasons whether one requirement is favored over the other.

Comment: great answer. I just wonder which approach is more popular? For which applications/fields?